# Unity Editor equivalent of Playmode Start()

Tags: unity

I am attempting to draw gizmos for easy debug in the editor. The gizmos code uses an array that gets populated during the start function. The array only needs to be populated once and may cause issues if its modified during runtime. As such, I cant call the method to populate the array in the `OnDrawGizmos()` method.

I could possibly use a singleton populate the array but that would require many other things to be changed as well. I am looking for an equivalent to `Start()` for when it is in Editor Mode. Is there a method in editor mode that execute once or an attribute for the `Start()` method to execute in editor mode?

Comment: I completely did not understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `OnEnable` in the `Editor` class.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.html

Here's some sample code from the docs:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

// Custom Editor using SerializedProperties.
// Automatic handling of multi-object editing, undo, and prefab overrides.
[CustomEditor(typeof(MyPlayer))]
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class MyPlayerEditor : Editor {
    SerializedProperty damageProp;
    SerializedProperty armorProp;
    SerializedProperty gunProp;

    void OnEnable () {
        // Setup the SerializedProperties.
        damageProp = serializedObject.FindProperty ("damage");
        armorProp = serializedObject.FindProperty ("armor");
        gunProp = serializedObject.FindProperty ("gun");
    }
...
```